# How to debug JavaScript in IE 9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have a site that uses JS and jQuery and works fine on all the browsers, but seems to have a bug in IE 9.

How do I debug javascript IE 9?

The error happens when you submit the form here: http://www.problemio.com/add_problem.php

and a test login is:
email: testing@problemio.com
password: testing

Comment: IE9 Developer Tools - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa740478

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press F12, go to "Script" and press "Start debugging" (or something like that. I'm using the german version).

If your script includes any errors, IE9 will show you an alert message.